# In App Billing Error: Item already owned

Tags: android, billing

Hi when I'm buying the test item ("android.test.purchased") for the first time, google play popup window says that transaction was successful (like this): [image]

First problem: After 'successful' transaction when I'm trying to buy same item it crash because it can't start another async operation [LOG](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6i6pa46hhwtntqp/log.txt)

Second problem: After changing fragment to another and then backing to donation fragment when I'm trying to buy another time test item it says that

`12-31 17:20:19.596: E/IabHelper(31546): In-app billing error: Unable to buy item, Error response: 7:Item Already Owned`

Problem is I want allow buying same item for multiple times.

Whole class code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ly1ocadh6c9om1/class.txt

Answer (score 3):

There are different types of products you can define in Google Play. Check out this section that explains how you can set your items to be 'consumed', that way allowing the user to re-purchase the same item after they've used it:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume